# How do I refactor nested subscribes with switchmap or other rxjs options when working with Firestore Observables?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I'm new to angular and have a hill to climb before I understand what's going on and working with observables from Firestore has me stumped. I need the ID field from one service call to get data from the following two service calls while avoiding the dreaded undefined. How do we do this?

```
this.myMatch = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("createdMatchIdKey");

this.golfDataService.GetSelectedMatch(this.myMatch)
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.match = result;
    this.setupTable(this.match.matchCourseId);
    this.golfDataService.GetSelectedGolfCourse(this.match.matchCourseId)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.course = result;
        console.log(this.course);
      })
    this.golfDataService.GetSelectedCourseTees(this.match.matchCourseId)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.tees = result;
        console.log(this.tees);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tees.length; i++) {
          this.golfDataService.GetHoles(this.tees[i].teeIdKey)
            .subscribe(result => {
              console.log(this.teeHoleInfo);
              this.teeHoleInfo.push(result);
              console.log(this.match);
            })
        }
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the RxJS "way" is to try to keep your pipeline as pure (no outside side effects) as possible. You can, of course, use `tap` to set your global variables along the way, but I think it's better in terms of testing, modularity, and extend-ability to not do any of that until after you've retrieved all your data.

This approach builds an object of the form:

```js
{
  match: any,
  course: any, 
  tees: any[],
  holes: any[]
}
```

- **match** is the result from `golfDataService.GetSelectedMatch`
- **course** is the result from `golfDataService.GetSelectedGolfCourse`
- **tees** is the result from `golfDataService.GetSelectedCourseTees`
- **holes** is the merged result from a whole slew of calls to `golfDataService.GetHoles` (There should be one call to `golfDataService.GetHoles` for each entry in **tees**)

The final result get subscribed to, and then all the consoles and assignments to your global variables gets called there.

```js
this.myMatch = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("createdMatchIdKey");

this.golfDataService.GetSelectedMatch(this.myMatch).pipe(
  mergeMap(match =>
    zip(
      this.golfDataService.GetSelectedGolfCourse(match.matchCourseId),
      this.golfDataService.GetSelectedCourseTees(match.matchCourseId)
    ).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(([course, tees])=> ({
        match,
        course,
        tees
      }))
    ),
    mergeMap(({match, course, tees}) => 
      zip(
        ...tees.map(tee => this.golfDataService.GetHoles(tee.teeIdKey))
      ).pipe(
        take(1),
        map(holes => ({
          match,
          course,
          tees,
          holes
        }))
      )
    )
  )
).subscribe(({match, course, tees, holes}) => {
  this.match = match;
  this.setupTable(this.match.matchCourseId);
  this.course = course;
  console.log(this.course);
  this.tees = tees;
  console.log(this.tees);
  this.teeHoleInfo = holes;
  console.log(this.teeHoleInfo);
});
```

One thing to note is that `fork(...)` is probably better than `zip(...).pipe(take(1))` but it only works when running observable that you're sure will complete.